# JS: java.lang.Exception: Failed resolving method read on class android.media.AudioRecord

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to use android.media.AudioRecord to save audio, initialization is OK, `startRecording()` is also called without error, but when I start reading audio from the buffer I got error `Failed resolving method read on class android.media.AudioRecord`.

Here is the code:

```
const SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
const RECORD_AUDIO = android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
const AudioRecord = android.media.AudioRecord;
const AudioFormat = android.media.AudioFormat;
const MediaRecorder = android.media.MediaRecorder;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    if (this.bufferSize == AudioRecord.ERROR || this.bufferSize == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
        this.bufferSize = SAMPLE_RATE * 2;
    }
    this.bufferSize = this.bufferSize * 10;
    this.audioBuffer = new Array(this.bufferSize / 2);

    if (!permissions.hasPermission(RECORD_AUDIO)) {
        permissions.requestPermission(RECORD_AUDIO).then(() => {
            this.createRecorder();
        }, (err) => {
            console.log('[BrowseComponent] ngOnInit, ', 'permissions error:', err);
        });
    }
    else {
        this.createRecorder();
    }

}

createRecorder() {
    this.record = new AudioRecord.Builder()
        .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
        .setAudioFormat(new AudioFormat.Builder()
            .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
            .setSampleRate(SAMPLE_RATE)
            .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO)
            .build())
        .setBufferSizeInBytes(this.bufferSize)
        .build();
    this.recordState = this.record && this.record.getState();
    if (this.recordState != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
        console.error('[BrowseComponent] createRecorder, ', 'AudioRecord can\'t initialize, state:', this.recordState);
        return;
    }
    console.log('[BrowseComponent] createRecorder, ', 'AudioRecord:', this.record);
}

startRecord() {
    this.recording = true;
    this.record.startRecording();
    this.shortsRead = 0;
    while (this.recording) {
        const numberOfShort = this.record.read(this.audioBuffer, 0, this.bufferSize);
        this.shortsRead += numberOfShort;

        // Do something with the audioBuffer
    }
}
```

`startRecord()` is called from `(tap)` button handler.
Any ideas what may be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you are passing JavaScript Array instead of the Java Primitive (short) typed Array, so the runtime is unable to identify a method that matches the given parameters.

Use `Array.create` method to typecast, refer the [docs here](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js#array-of-objects) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like you are right. Now method is called successfully. It always return -2 for some reason but this is another story...

Comment: -2 is a status code that the 'read' method returns. It actually corresponds to a "bad value error". See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord#ERROR_BAD_VALUE). I'm running into a similar issue, hoping someone knows what's going on.